# How can I do a timeout in PHP?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a function similar to setTimeout() (JavaScript) for PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3435418/is-there-a-function-similar-to-settimeout-javascript-for-php)

Is there any way to do a timeout in PHP? Something similar to setTimeout() in Javascript.
I want to insert data in database after 5 minutes.

Edit: Also. It will do another things after 5 minutes. A function will be executed. Then, the approach shouldn't be with the database. A hang is undesirable

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3435418/is-there-a-function-similar-to-settimeout-javascript-for-php

Answer (score 4):

If the database does not already have a `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` field, add one. Then, insert the row immediately but set that `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` field to `DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)`.

Then, in whatever code you have `SELECT`ing from this table, include `WHERE ts <= NOW()` (where `ts` is the name of your `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` field)

I use this technique in one of my Cron scripts to simulate it running non-stop when actually it's running once every 15 minutes, by using a random interval between 0 and 15 minutes, and it works really well.

Comment: This seems to be the best approach to me.

Comment: It will do another things after 5 minutes. A function will be executed. Then, the approach shouldn't be with the database.

Comment: @Kolink. Can you point me an example? How add I a `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`? How set `that CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` field to `DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)`?

Comment: Ok. I've understood. But when you say: `WHERE ts >= NOW()` I that it would be `WHERE ts <= NOW()`

Comment: Ah you're right. I'm sorry, I got confused. It is indeed `<=` that you want.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use something like a cron job or task scheduler depending on where you are hosted. PHP is not event driven.

Answer (score 1):

Like others said, there is no "clean" way. You better use a cron job or scheduler-like utility provided by the environment in which you are hosted. **And I strongly advise you not to use `sleep()`**.

*An alternative would be the one of completely changing your approach*. Why don't you put the data in the DB immediately, but give it a different "meaning" after 5 minutes?
e.g. you post a new row with a timestamp. When you read, you filter out all the rows that have been inserted after 5 minutes ago.

Comment: It hangs the script, which still runs but it is unresponsive. A bad time for HTTP clients :)

Comment: It will do another things after 5 minutes. A function will be executed. Then, the approach shouldn't be with the database. Some idea?

Answer (score 0):

The php `sleep()` function is the way to go.  More details in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6486364/is-there-a-set-time-out-equivalent-in-php). In your case the code might be:

```
<?

sleep(300); // Or 'sleep(5*60);' to make it more readable.
echo 'Do something!';

?>
```

Comment: `sleep()` hangs the script

Comment: you are right. I will edit it

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure why you need this but you can use

```
sleep(300);
```

For more http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php

But I would use a more elegant solution, again this is dependant on what you can or cannot do.

I would store the data in a temporary file. Then use [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) to run a script every five minutes to check weather or not a data file exists. If it does, take the file and insert into the database.

Comment: You are right, late in the day :D

Comment: Sleep will hang the script. It is not only inelegant, but unacceptable.

Comment: Yes I know, I answered as he asked, hence why the offer for a more elegant solution underneath.

Comment: `sleep()` hangs the script

Comment: @vicenrele that is what its designed to do, Again im not sure exactly why you want this. I think what you are after is threading, and PHP is not really the best language for this you can look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209774/does-php-have-threading. You can try to fork() a child and call your sleep() inside the child, so your parent is allowed to continue.

Comment: my intention is to execute a function after 5 minutes. This function change a flag y database. I have a web application which the users can use it for 5 minutes in demo version (only one user both). In the client I use the page is closed with Javascript and sends an Ajax request to reset the flag. But if the user leaves of the page 5 minutes before, the flag isn't reset. For 5 minutes isn't so important, but if the demo is for 15 minutes, I think that something like is necessary

Comment: @Angel.King.47. Thanks for response. I can't try to fork() a child because Apache servers don't support `pcntl_fork()`. But It was a great idea.

Comment: You can fire an ajax request, when the browser is closed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704533/intercept-page-exit-event

Comment: Ok. But not work if the client loses Internet connection

Comment: @vicenrele Am I right in assuming that you want a session to timeout, if the user is inactive for N minutes?

Comment: No. The flag indicates if a user can do log in, because only one user both can use the application. When the user closes the demo, the flag should be reset also since php (not only by ajax request because it's possible that the user loses the Internet connection and ajax request isn't realized) . Then another user could user the demo application

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164507/allow-one-session-only-at-a-time

Comment: That question is for a unique user in different computers. The solution is the same that mine but without timeout. But timeout is my problem